# How do I separate this into two files?

Tags: python, function, variables

This works altogether, however doesn't when they are inside separate files, like so:
main.py

```
from write import *

def write():
    global text
    text = "this is a test"
    colour()

write()
```

colour.py

```
import sys
from time import sleep

blue = '\033[0;34m'

def colour():
    for char in text:
        sleep(0.05)
        sys.stdout.write(blue)
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()
    sleep(0.5)
```

Error is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    write()
  File "main.py", line 6, in write
    colour()
  File "/home/runner/Function-Test/colour.py", line 7, in colour
    for char in text:
NameError: name 'text' is not defined
```

Comment: What do you mean by *when I move the write() into another file it prints a space and then ends*?

Comment: When i move the function write() into a separate file it doesn't type out 'this is a test' in the console, it goes blank and then the program ends.

Comment: Into a separate file? You mean importing the function write to another python program?

Comment: I can write out the separate files if you'd like

Comment: I'm sorry I do not understand what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I've updated it to what i want, but isn't working

Comment: global variables do not transfer between files. You should pass `text` to the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I would do it if I understand correctly:

write.py

```
from colour import colour

def write():
    text = "this is a test"
    colour(text)

write()
```

colour.py

```
import sys
from time import sleep

blue = '\033[0;34m'

def colour(text):
    for char in text:
        sleep(0.05)
        sys.stdout.write(blue)
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()
    sleep(0.5)
```

Result:

`this is a test` Written slowly in Blue.